# Weird behavior of pagination

Tags: discussion, bug, pagination

When you go to questions, in the pagination, the last page is 482051 (or
482171, that depends on how many times do you reload the page). But, when you go there, e.g., to https://stackoverflow.com/questions?tab=votes&page=482171, or to https://stackoverflow.com/questions?tab=votes&page=482051, the questions are each time different, and sometimes the page is even not found.

The issue persists both in Chrome 122.0.6261.94 and in Firefox 123 on Ubuntu 22.04.

Comment: You're probably seeing different caches on different servers. There's a ___lot___ going on to affect what questions are shown that far down the page. New questions, deletions, migrations, etc etc etc... I'd be surprised if the complete list of questions is cached consistently over every server SE is running.

Comment: It goes even worse: I can't go to your first URL, althgou the site tells me the last page should be "https://stackoverflow.com/questions?tab=votes&page=482172" :-) (Working incognito using Google Chrome on Windows-10)

Comment: The rate is on the order of 3-4 per minute on average. It is a whole new page of 15 every 4 minutes.